# Why code inside ELCimagePickerController is not executed?

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, elcimagepickercontroller

This is my first iOS application. Swift 3 is used. I am using `ELCImagePickerController` to select multiple images. My code successfully opens library and I can select multiple images. However, on Cancel or finish selecting, nothing happened and no dismissal occur to the albums. My code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    
    super.viewDidLoad(  
    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

func elcimagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)   
}
```

func  elcimagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
 {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

```
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you attempting to provide two delegate methods with nearly the same name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ELCImagePickerController does not back to viewController in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30883871/elcimagepickercontroller-does-not-back-to-viewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: oh - it's just a typo here I pasted twice but even when it was one I got same problem,

Comment: I edited the code above - so would you let me know what could possibly be causing that the photo library never dismissed on cancel or once done picking

Comment: See the duplicate I linked to in my earlier comment.

Comment: let me add that elcimagepickercontroller function and elcimagepickercontrollerDidcancel were not available to be picked form the xcode list of unctions I wrote it manually - is that okay and normal?